# How to pass other template parameter when template function uses parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

Is it possible to have other template parameter when function/class uses parameter pack?

I try simple sum function. I want to print something using `template Printer` class. How to do that? How to tell compiler to specially "mark" first parameter... or there is some workaround.

Below code generates errors.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
double sum(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename Printer, typename T, typename... Rest>
double sum(Printer printer, T t, Rest... rest)
{
    printer.print();

    return t + sum(rest...);
}

struct P
{
    void print() { std::cout << "= " << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    P printer;
    std::cout << sum(printer, 2, 3, 4.1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to print something for every member of the pack? Or just print once?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica No. Just once.
I know this is stupid exmaple but I tried to make it simple.
In other words I would like to have parameter expansion except the first one.. or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an error because the only `sum` overload that accepts more than a single argument expects the first argument to be a printer object. Since you want to print only once, the cleanest approach would be to separate the summation into its own function entirely:

```
template <typename T>
double sum_impl(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
double sum_impl(T t, Rest... rest)
{
    return t + sum(rest...);
}
```

and then use that in `sum`

```
template <typename Printer, typename T, typename... Rest>
double sum(Printer printer, T t, Rest... rest)
{
    printer.print();

    return sum_impl(t, rest...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer and try to prepare much complicated example for template class.

Comment: @peter55555 no matter how complicated the example, StoryTeller's advice holds. Complex code is best expressed as composition of single-purpose components.

Comment: @RichardHodges How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712888 Is it possible to use above solution?